# HTML5 Yoga studio page not displaying properly

Tags: css, html

I am trying to get this webpage to show with navigation buttons on the left side of the page. My webpage works great from the previous homework assignment but since I have updated my css sheet now the page displays all messed up. Any help would be awesome!

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #3f2860;
  color: #3f2860;
  font-family: Veranda, Arial, sans-serif;
}

header {
  background-color: #9bc1c2;
  background-image: url(lilyheader.jpg);
  background-position: right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 150px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-left: 2em;
}

nav {
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 1em;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 1em;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

nav a:link {
  color: #3F2860;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: #497777;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #A26100;
  border: 3px inset #333333;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0
}

main {
  margin-left: 170px;
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding: 2em;
  display: block;
}

floatleft {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4em;
}

.studio {
  font-style: italic;
}

.company {
  font-style: italic;
}

footer {
  background-color: #9bc1c2;
  font-size: .60em;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

clear {
  clear: both;
}

#wrapper {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  min-width: 1200px;
  max-width: 1480px;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

header,
nav,
main,
footer {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Path of Light Yoga Studio</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="yoga.css">
  <!-- [if it IE 9]>
    <script src="html5shiv.js>
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Path of Light Yoga Studio</h1>
    </header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>;
        <li><a href="classes.html">Classes</a></li>;
        <li><a href="schedule.html">Schedule</a></li>;
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>;
      </ul>

    </nav>
    <main>
      <img class="floatleft" src="yogadoor2.jpg" alt="Door to yoga studio" width="220" height="370">
      <h2>Find Your Inner Light</h2>
      <p><span class="company">Path of Light Yoga Studio</span> provides all levels of yoga practice in a tranquil, peaceful environment. Whether you are new to yoga or an experienced practitioner, our dedicated instructions can develop a practice to meet
        your needs. Let your inner light shine at the <span class="company">Path Of Light Yoga Studio</span>.
      </p>
      <ul>
        <li>Hatha, Vinyasa, and Restorative Yoga classes</li>
        <li>Drop-ins welcome</li>
        <li>Mats, blocks, and blankets provided</li>
        <li>Relax in our Serenity Lounge before or after your class</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear">
        <span class="company">Path of Light Yoga Studio</span><br> 612 Serenity Way<br> El Dorado, CA 96162<br><br> 888-555-5555
        <br><br>
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
      Copyright &copy; 2016 Path of Light Yoga<br>
      <a href="mailto:Brittany@Tracy.com">Brittany@tracy.com</a><br><br>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Link to what the page is supposed to look like](http://www.chuck57.com/Chapter6/Case/FreedCh6CaseYoga/index.html)

[image]

Comment: converted to snippet, so what is the "messed up" part?

Comment: define messed up

Comment: If you click on the link to the way the webpage is supposed to be set up, when I run my page on internet explorer it appears like there is an issue with my css page and the way it is formatting the home page. The text is not in the proper spot, the left side navigation buttons do not show up, the image will not display. I have read my book several times but I am not sure how to fix this

Comment: @brittmoe09 it mostly looks pretty close. You have some semicolons between the buttons but that's easy to remove. The image not showing up is probably just because it's not in the same directory as your html file. It won't work online ( here ) because the image isn't hosted anywhere.

Comment: if you could take a screenshot it could help us help you.

Comment: I uploaded a screen shot. It shows differently then when I run the code snippet on here.

Comment: After going through everything line by line I was able to get the page to load correctly. Thanks for everyone's help!